# openUrl is not redirecting to safari in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, ios8.3

I have my old application which is working fine till iOS 8.2. In one button action I have to **open safari** using  `openUrl` and this is working fine for the device with iOS 8.2. But when I run it in iOS 8.3 then its not opening the safari and when I tried to print it then its returning `NO`.

Is there any change in iOS 8.3 for openUrl method?

**Edit 1:**

```
NSString *loginUrl=[object sighnUpUrl];

            NSLog(@"%d",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginUrl]]);


            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginUrl]];
```

I am just using the url of login page of my web.

**Edit 2:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
```

I tried the same code and getting `Failed to open url:http://www.stackoverflow.com`.

**Edit 3:**

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.de"];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
        }
```

When I tried the same above code then its entering the if block but still unable to the safari.

**Note: All the above Codes are working in iOS 8.2.**

Comment: can you add the code?

Comment: wanna show the specific line(s)?

Comment: Kindly share your code so that we can help you out. Issue could be in Simulator, have you tried it in Real Device? Thanks!

Comment: I have added the code in the question.

Comment: @Imran Please share the URL you are getting in loginUrl

Comment: That is my company's url.Even though I use  "http://www.google.com" its not opening google. Is there any settings required?  same as this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

Comment: you **HAVE** to start the URL with **http://**

Comment: Thanks for you help.issue was because of MDM.please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through all the answers and I know all of them will work.The issue was on the other side.I am using **Mobile Device Management** in my app.Some one from the server side had disabled safari using MDM.Unfortunately for the device with iOS 8.2 it was enabled and for the devices with iOS 8.3 it was disabled which made me think its an iOS issue.So while safari is disabled using MDM it can't open any url.My Bad.Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

this is the way to go:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.de"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

Comment: Its entering the if block but still unable to open safari.please check.

Comment: that is weird. if you are using the simulator try to **Reset Content and Settings...**

Comment: No I am using device.May be some settings because its happening in both iPad and iPhone device.

Comment: did you delete the app from your device completely and tried again? - cause on my device (iphone 6, iOS 8.3) it is totally working.

Comment: Yes tried that.Are you using iOS 8.3.If you confirm its working your side on IOS 8.3 then I will check some settings rather than code.

Comment: Thanks for you help.issue was because of MDM.please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) {
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
```

Comment: Its returning "Failed to open url:http://www.stackoverflow.com". please check from your side.

Comment: Thanks for you help.issue was because of MDM.please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

**Edit:**

```
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:yourURL];
```

Try to place your URL here & check whether it returns True or False.

Comment: Thanks for you help.issue was because of MDM.please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ios8.3 .apk file received by e-mail, can not open other applications, it may be a BUG ios8.3 of

Comment: This could be a comment